# Solr Qtime difference to real time

Tags: solr, solrj

i am trying to find out what causes the difference between the Qtime and the actual response time in my Solr application.
The SolrServer is running on the same maschine as the program generating the queries.
I am getting Qtimes in average around 19ms but it takes 30ms to actually get my response.
This may sound like it is not much, but i am using Solr for some obscure stuff where every millisecond counts.

I figured that the time difference is not caused by Disk I/O since using RAMDirectoryFactory did not speed up anything.

Using a SolrEmbeddedServer instead of a SolrHttpServer did not cause a speedup aswell (so it is not Jetty what causes the difference?)

Is the data transfer between the query-program and the Solr-instance causing the time difference? And even more important, how can i minimize this time?

regards

Comment: Have you tried to disable logging?

Comment: thanks for the input, i have disabled logging in the log4j.properties file. This caused no speedup. Do i have to diable logging somewhere else too?

Comment: Hm, ok. Have you restarted the server after that? Do you still see output in the log file on each request?

Comment: There are no more log output files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known [FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FAQ#Why_is_the_QTime_Solr_returns_lower_then_the_amount_of_time_I.27m_measuring_in_my_client.3F):

> **Why is the QTime Solr returns lower then the amount of time I'm
>   measuring in my client?**
>
> > "QTime" only reflects the amount of time Solr spent processing the
> >     request. It does not reflect any time spent reading the request from
> >     the client across the network, or writing the response back to the
> >     client. (This should hopefully be obvious since the QTime is actually
> >     included in body of the response.)
> >
> > The time spent on this network I/O can be a non-trivial contribution
> >     to the the total time as observed from clients, particularly because
> >     there are many cases where Solr can stream "stored fields" for the
> >     response (ie: requested by the "fl" param) directly from the index as
> >     part of the response writing, in which case disk I/O reading those
> >     stored field values may contribute to the total time observed by
> >     clients outside of the time measured in QTime.

> How to minimize this time?

Not sure if it will have any effect, but make sure you are using javabin format, not json or xml (wt=javabin)